# Only include specific attributes as input options for form generated by scaffold in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used a generator to create a scaffold for "Person".  I passed in the three attributes of the model: height, weight, age

```
rails g scaffold Person
```

This did what was expected, and created everything i needed to get going, including a ready-made CRUD.  However, I want age to be an optional input.  The form that was autogenerated has fields to input all three attributes, but I only want inputs for height and weight to be displayed.

```
<%= render 'form', person: @person%>
```

How can I update this so that only height and weight are shown in the person/new view, but still allow age to be entered in a view linked to another action?

Comment: Have you tried editing `'form'`?

Comment: I am a total RoR noob.  I reviewed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html to try to build a form with only the two inputs I needed, but apparently the values were being passed an nill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to copy the contents of the `_form` template and paste it directly into the `new` template instead of the the row where it calls `render 'form'`.

Then once you have done that, you can modify which inputs you want to have in the `new` template, without it affecting the other actions that are rendering the `_form` template.

Just note that in the code you copy from the `_form` template, you must replace any reference to `person` with `@person` instead.

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly what I was looking for.